# I can not found bug, which causes infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops

The task of this program is to extract gods from a custom array(Link), according to mythology, and then sort them alphabetically into two new array.(It's exercise from PP&P using C++) Problem is, that somewhere the default array "gods" is changed to infinite array. I'm sitting on this problem for 2 hours debugging and can not find the bug. Can someone please help me ?

## Link.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

struct God {
    std::string name;
    std::string mythology;
    std::string vehicle;
    std::string weapon;
    God(std::string n, std::string m = "none", std::string v = "none", std::string w = "none")
        :name{n}, mythology{m}, vehicle{v}, weapon{w} {}
    void print_god() const;
};

bool operator==(const God a, const God b);

class Link
{
public: 
    God god;

    Link(God god_In, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr)
        :god{god_In}, prev{p}, succ{s} {}

    Link* insert(Link* n);
    Link* add(Link* n);
    Link* add_ordered(Link* s);

    Link* erase();
    Link* find(const God g);

    Link* advance(int n) const;

    Link* next()const { return succ; }
    Link* previous()const { return prev; }
private:
    Link* succ;
    Link* prev;
};

void print_all(Link*);
```

## Link.cpp

```
#include "Link.h"
#include <iostream>

void God::print_god() const{
    std::cout << '(' << name << '|' << mythology << '|' << vehicle << '|' << weapon << ')';
}

bool operator==(const God a, const God b) {
    if (a.name != b.name) return false;
    if (a.mythology != b.mythology) return false;
    if (a.vehicle != b.vehicle) return false;
    if (a.weapon != b.weapon) return false;
    return true;
}

Link* Link::insert(Link* s) {

    if (s == nullptr)return this;
    s->succ = this;
    if (prev) prev->succ = s;
    s->prev = prev;
    
    prev = s;
    return s;
}

Link* Link::add(Link* s) {
    if (s == nullptr)return this;
    s->prev = this;
    if (succ) succ->prev = s;
    s->succ = succ;
    
    succ = s;
    return this;
}

Link* Link::add_ordered(Link* s) {
    if (s == nullptr) return nullptr;
    
    Link* a = this;
    if (s->god.name < god.name)
        return a->insert(s);
    while (s->god.name > a->god.name) {
        if (a->succ == nullptr) {//none succesor
            a->add(s);
            return this;
        }
        a = a->succ;
    }
    a->insert(s);
    return this;
}

Link* Link::erase() {
    if (prev == nullptr && succ == nullptr) return this;
    if (prev) prev->succ = succ;
    if (succ) succ->prev = prev;
    return succ;
}

Link* Link::find(const God g) {
    Link* p = this;
    while (p) {
        if (p->god == g) return p;
        p = p->succ;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

//get n succesor +>>> -<<<
Link* Link::advance(int n) const{
    Link* p = nullptr;
    if (n > 0) {
        if (succ == nullptr) return nullptr;
        p = this->succ;
        while (n--) {
            if (p == nullptr) return nullptr;
            p = p->succ;
        }
    }
    else if (n < 0) {
        if (prev == nullptr) return nullptr;
        p = this->prev;
        while (n--) {
            if (p == nullptr) return nullptr;
            p = p->prev;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

void print_all(Link* p) {
    if (p == nullptr) return;
    std::cout << '{';
    while (p) {
        p->god.print_god();
        if (p=p->next()) std::cout << ',';
    }
    std::cout << '}';
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include "Link.h"

int main()
{
    Link* gods = new Link{ God{"Thor", "Norse"}};
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Odin", "Norse"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Athena", "Greek"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Ares", "Greek"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Loki", "Norse"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Hera", "Greek"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Poseidon", "Greek"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Zeus", "Greek"} });
    gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Freia", "Norse"} });

    print_all(gods);
    std::cout << '\n';

    Link* ordered_norse_gods = nullptr;
    Link* ordered_greek_gods = nullptr;


    while (gods != nullptr) {
        if (gods->god.mythology == "Norse") {
            if (ordered_norse_gods == nullptr) {
                ordered_norse_gods = new Link{ gods->god };
                if (gods->next() == nullptr)
                    break;
                gods = gods->next();
                continue;
            }
            ordered_norse_gods = ordered_norse_gods->add_ordered(gods);
        }
        else if (gods->god.mythology == "Greek") {
            if (ordered_greek_gods == nullptr) {
                ordered_greek_gods = new Link{ gods->god };
                if (gods->next() == nullptr)
                    break;
                gods = gods->next();
                continue;
            }
            ordered_greek_gods = ordered_greek_gods->add_ordered(gods);
        }
        if (gods->next() == nullptr)
            break;
        gods = gods->next();
    }

    print_all(ordered_norse_gods);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_all(ordered_greek_gods);
    std::cout << '\n';
    delete gods;
    delete ordered_norse_gods;
    delete ordered_greek_gods;
}
```

Comment: Your test data should consist of only two or three items, not 8.  If your code fails with 2 or 3 items, it isn't going to work with 8 items.  By reducing the number of items, it will make your debugging efforts much more simpler.

Comment: Also, why is `main` doing so much work?  Shouldn't all of that work be done within the `Link` class?  The `main` should simply consist of declaring a `Link` class, and calling `add`, `erase`, etc.  It shouldn't be entangled in trying to maintain the `Link` class itself.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn to use your debugger.  It will let you step through the code line-by-line, inspecting values of every variable along the way.  It's likely that one of your modification operations has created a pointer cycle.

Comment: The problem isn't in number of items, because it makes infinit Zeus. So it must be somewhere in second iteration.  The exercise was just add function add_order() and use it.

Comment: @0x5453 That's exactly what I was doing and yes somewhere it is, but can not find it. For me it's close too 0Am so maybe I need to go sleep and take a brake.

Comment: @HarryTra *The problem isn't in number of items* -- The point that I am making is that it serves no purpose creating something with more items than necessary to duplicate the error.   So again, if it doesn't work with 3 items, it isn't going to work with 8 items, so why make your debugging job more difficult by trying to keep track of 8 items?

Comment: Yeah I understand the point.

Comment: Think about what add_ordered is doing.

Comment: @HarryTra -- Take a look at your `main` program in general, even at the start.  `Link* gods = new Link{ God{"Thor", "Norse"} }; gods = gods->insert(new Link{ God{"Odin", "Norse"} });` -- You basically took the original `gods` pointer from the first call to `insert`, and overwrite it on the next `insert` call. and you overwrite that second pointer with the next call to `insert`, etc..  That right there is a major flaw in your program -- how are you going to go back and delete all of those allocated pointers?  That's why I mentioned why `main` is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Then how is `add_ordered` supposed to work if the original list that you created is not ordered?  Either your list starts out sorted and remains sorted, or it doesn't.  Overall, what you have is an attempt of a doubly-linked list that has many flaws.

Comment: Yeah I think that's point of the book. Show the basics and then with each chapter build on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing elements from the list that you currently iterating into `add_ordered`. The issue is that your code doesn't expect elements of one list to be added to another list.

You need to allocate new Link before adding it to another list, you can do it by replacing:

```cpp
ordered_norse_gods = ordered_norse_gods->add_ordered(gods);
```

With:

```cpp
ordered_norse_gods = ordered_norse_gods->add_ordered(new Link{ gods->god });
```

And the same thing for the second `add_ordered` call, and after that, it'll work just fine.

The reason why you got infinite loop is that `add_ordered` changed `prev` and `succ` pointer in your loop variable `gods`.

Comment: Ohh I got it. So in short I try to join two lists, but I want to just copy god value into new allocated list, because I changed the value of gods in add_ordered and this of course applied to gods list. Thank you :D